# Hosted macOS Preview deploy ipa to App Center

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, azure-pipelines

I have set up a hosted mac os preview build for a Xamarin app.  All the steps complete except for 'deploy ipa'  The publish artifact says nothing will be added. Here is are the settings from the copy files to as well as the output

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you set the incorrect `Source Folder` or `Contents pattern` in Copy Files step. That caused no files were copied to target folder for publishing.

Please check the logs of **Copy Files** step to see if the `*.ipa` files are really copied to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`.

If no files copied, then just check the **build logs** to get the real working directory (Source Folder in copy step) and make sure the `*.ipa` files are generated in the directory. (By default it's `$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)` on my side.)

If the real working directory is just the Source Folder `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` you specified in Copy step, then the problem should be the **contents pattern**.

> Contents specify minimatch pattern filters (one on each line) that you
>   want to apply to the list of files to be copied. For example:
>
> ** copies all files in the root folder.
>
> **\ * copies all files in the root folder and all files in all sub-folders.
>
> **\ bin copies files in any sub-folder named bin.

Comment: Thanks, it was the fact that I had 'build for simulator' selected that the file was not getting copied to the output directory.  I saw to set that in the documentation.  Not sure why.

Comment: Now I'm getting a different error.  Cannot POST /v0.1/apps/https://appcenter.ms/users/<orgname>/apps/<appname>/release_uploads    when following the URL without 'release_uploads' correctly navigates to the app

Comment: For anyone interested,  I had the slug wrong.  Works now